# I'm spent for to mean people spend money for me

Tags: sentence-construction

In the context of money, can I use:
"I'm spent for" or "I'm spent money for" to mean people spend money for me?

Answer (score 1):

No. As far as I know, "I'm spent." has one meaning: I am very tired, exhausted.

For your meaning, "People spend money on me."